# Listener for clicking on any area of ​the SearchView

Tags: android, kotlin, search, navigation, searchview

I have a SearchView and I am using navigation components. I made such logic that when I click on the search button on the keyboard from fragment A, there is a transition with the transfer of the SearchView text to fragment B.

And here I am in fragment B, and the text from SearchView in fragment A was passed to the input field of SearchView in fragment B, and now I need that when I click on any area of ​​the SearchView, it will go back to fragment A, while android: `iconifiedByDefault = "false"` , how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this simple code should work.

in Fragment B:

```
val searchView = view?.findViewById<SearchView>(R.id.yourSearchViewId)
searchView?.setOnClickListener { /* go back to fragment A */ }
```

EDITED:
Made it work with these 2 listeners:

```
/* this is invoked when you click on anything but the input field */
binding.searchView.setOnTouchListener { v, event -> // ignore all touch events
    /* go back to Fragment A */
    true
}
            
/* this is invoked when you click on the input field */
binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener { view, b ->
    /* go back to Fragment A */
}
```

Comment: I did something like this: `binding.searchView.setOnClickListener {}` and it didn't work

Comment: Yep, this should work as well :)

Comment: I already tried it, it doesn't work, this only works outside the text input area

Comment: @TapchylovRadin edited the answer, now it should work

Comment: it only works if iconifiedByDefault = "true" and if iconifiedByDefault = "false" then it doesn't work

Comment: What's the problem when iconifiedByDefault == "false"? I just tested this and it worked fine

Comment: I have when clicked it focuses on the search input field and navigation safe args doesn't fire `binding.searchView.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            openAgain(args.query)
            true
        }`

Comment: Did you use the OnQueryTextFocusChangeListener as well? Because it's the listener invoked when you click on the input field

Comment: yes but that doesn't work either. 
or I didn't use it correctly, I also called the openAgain (args.query) method inside it

Comment: But you used both of these listeners at the same time, right?

Comment: Oh no, all this time I used OnFocusChangeListener, not OnQueryFocusChangeListener, I just changed it and it worked, I apologize much, but I got an error with navigation, but I fixed it by putting the check on the 2nd click.
Thank you! And sorry for my English